# Getting Json Output from Byte Array

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest, serialization

I just started a new project on WCF and to be honest I'm very new at this with limited knowledge.

So what I'm trying to do is open a file that is stored in my computer (e.g. word, pdf, etc.) and display the contents in the webpage in JSon format. I converted the file in a byte array and tried to display the `Stream`. When I did that it asked me to open the file or save it. I don't want that - I just want the contents of the file to be displayed on my local host when i call the method.

Here's what I have:

```
public string GetRawFile()
    {
        string file = @"C:\.....\TestFile.pdf";
        byte[] rawFile = File.ReadAllBytes(file);


        //Stream stream = new MemoryStream(rawFile);
        //DataContractJsonSerializer obj = newDataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(string));
        //string result = obj.ReadObject(stream).ToString();

        //Deserializing
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
        stream.Write(rawFile, 0, rawFile.Length);

        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        Object obj = (Object) binForm.Deserialize(stream);

        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer xyz = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        string ejson = xyz.Serialize(obj);

        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
        return ejson;
    }
```

I'm trying to return a string and it's not working, but when I return just the stream it's popping up the "openwith" message.

Also should I use the `GET` or `POST` on my datacontract. I'm using REST in C#.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your file actually contains json. If that is the case just do this;

```
string file = File.ReadAllText("C:\path\to\file.extension");
```

You're making the problem a lot more complicated than it needs to be. Just read the file and return it's data as a string. I think you want to use GET for the http method. Generally speaking, you all use post if you're adding new content. If for example the users request would cause the application to write some data to a file or data base then you would typically use POST for the http method. If they're just requesting data, you almost always use GET.

Comment: I just want to import any file and get the output in Json....is that even possible....i'm trying to open a regular pdf and that is the reason i'm converting the file into a stream.

Comment: @Arka In order to do that you'll have to deserialize your pdf and a byte array won't suffice for doing that. The format is proprietary so it's not like you can just read it as plain text. In order to read a file as json it must actually contain valid json. Otherwise you'll need to construct some objects in code then you can serialize those into json strings but you can't just take the bytes from any random thing and write them as json.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response...do you know how can i deserialize PDF or a word file into Json? any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @Arka you can't directly. First you need to read the file and store it's data in some object, then you serialize the object into json. Why are you trying to store a PDF or Word doc as json anyway? Those don't really seem like compatible formats to me.